# Sort array of objects in accordance with initial array state

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an initial array of objects that I build table from, it looks like this:

```
const headCells = [
  {
    id: 'status',
    label: 'Status',
  },
  {
    id: 'group',
    label: 'Group',
  },
  {
    id: 'name',
    label: 'Name',
  },
  {
    id: 'hypervisor',
    label: 'Hypervisor',
  },
]
```

At some point I can filter my array (for example - remove first two objects). Based on my react app logic I can add the same items in different order, but I should keep the same structure as my initial array was. For example, if I add 'group' and then 'status' object (after removing it), the result should be: (status -> group, not group -> status).

My first thought was to find an index in the original array and then insert new item to the array based on that index:

```
let key = 'Group'
let idx = headCells.findIndex(item => item.label === key)

modifiedArray.splice(idx, 0, { id: key.toLowerCase(), label: name })
```

Seems it works as I want.

Is there a better way for keeping sorted array after filtering in accordance with the initial one?

```
 //initial array 
[
  {
    id: 'status',
    label: 'Status',
  },
  {
    id: 'group',
    label: 'Group',
  },
  {
    id: 'name',
    label: 'Name',
  },
  {
    id: 'hypervisor',
    label: 'Hypervisor',
  },
]
 //expected output after removing object with id 'group':
  {
    id: 'status',
    label: 'Status',
  },
  {
    id: 'name',
    label: 'Name',
  },
  {
    id: 'hypervisor',
    label: 'Hypervisor',
  },
]
//expected output after adding object with id 'group' (add by key string, keep the same object place as it was in the initial array):
[
  {
    id: 'status',
    label: 'Status',
  },
  {
    id: 'group',
    label: 'Group',
  },
  {
    id: 'name',
    label: 'Name',
  },
  {
    id: 'hypervisor',
    label: 'Hypervisor',
  },
]
```

Comment: what you tried? also provide your expected output

Comment: btw, the data structure is not valid without keys. or take an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain a `initial order` array, and then sort on the basis of index of that array.

```js
var headCells = [ { id: 'status', label: 'Status', }, { id: 'group', label: 'Group', }, { id: 'name', label: 'Name', }, { id: 'hypervisor', label: 'Hypervisor', }, { id: 'status', label: 'Status', }, { id: 'name', label: 'Name', }];

var initalOrder = [...new Set(headCells.map(({id})=>id))];

// after initial array declared add some more data to your array for testing
headCells.push({id:'someotherid', label:'SomeLabel'});
headCells.push({id:'status', label:'newly added status'});

var sortedResult = headCells.sort((a,b)=>{
  aa = initalOrder.indexOf(a.id);
  bb = initalOrder.indexOf(b.id);
  return (aa == -1 ? initalOrder.length : aa)-(bb == -1 ? initalOrder.length : bb);
});

console.log(sortedResult);
```

So whenever you add an object whose `id` is not present in the `initialorder` array will be moved to the last of the array while sorting.